# regex .exec() loosing first digit of matched string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am building a nodeJS JavaScript application and am trying to use regex to process some markdown files.

I have the following code:

````
var title = /```.(.*?\n)/.exec(codeBlock);
console.log('Code: ' + codeBlock);
console.log('Title: ' + title[1]);
````

and the output is:

````
Code: ```TypeScript
animationSet = new animationModule.Animation([{
    target: view,
    rotate: 360,
    duration: 3000,
    iterations: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY,
    curve: view.ios ? UIViewAnimationCurve.UIViewAnimationCurveLinear : new android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator
}]);
animationSet.play().catch((e) => {
    console.log("Animation stopped!");
});
// Call animationSet.cancel() to stop it;
```
Title: ypeScript
````

Notice rather than the full "title" I am looking the first character. If I add a space, such that first line of the code block is ```` ``` TypeScript ```` then I get an output of `Title: TypeScript`.

Where is my first character going and how can I get it back!

Comment: Use `.*` for a faster regex, and `$` instead of `\n` for broader compatibility. You will have to use the `m` modifier though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Helpful tool](http://regexr.com/)

hmmmm your capture group starts after first charater

````
/```.(.*?\n)/
````

it says :

- ``` - this 3 charaters
- . - one any charater <- here is your charater consumed but not captured
- ( - start capture group
- ...etc

so valid pattern will be :

````
```(.*?\n)
````